# PostgreSQL connections query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 db tables, nodes and edges. Nodes table has id that is primary key, and edges table has 2 columns, id1 and id2, and those are foreign keys to nodes.id. That should represent connections between nodes(one edge contains two nodes)

If edges table contains for example

```
id1  id2
1     3
1     5
2     5
```

I need a query that, when I type 1, pg should return in single cell 3,5. Something like this:

```
connections
3,5
```

What that query should be like?

Comment: What if data have one more row with value 1, 6 then what would be result ?

Answer (score 1):

Merging multiple rows requires an [aggregation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) (and a `GROUP BY` clause if you need multiple final results).

For this case, `string_agg` is the one to use.

e.g.

```
Select string_agg(id2, ', ') as connections from table where id1=1 group by id1
```

Comment: Never knew string_agg existed, looks very powerful; is it new?

Comment: @JeffUK it's been around for a long time. Checking docs for older versions shows it was added with 9.0 (released 2010-09-20). array_agg is older and can be used to similar effect (with an array to string function, or for OP's question, just a to string and some trimming).

Comment: Thanks, I  only just noticed this was a postgresql question (not sure how I ended up here!) I was actually thinking of MS SQL Server,  Coincidentally it's only just been added to the latest version.